# Why am I getting an error when viewing stackoverflow in IE7?

Tags: status-norepro, bug

I'm using Internet Explorer 7.0.5730.13 and I am getting the following error popping up:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?

Line: 1
Error: Syntax error
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

This occurs when I visit any page including the main page.  I have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: I am using IE7 version 7.0.5730.11 and have no such problem.

Answer (score 1):

TheTXI seems to have hit the nail on the head.  If that doesn't correct the issue though, it is certainly possible that you are not getting the Javascript files loaded onto your PC from Google.  The SO sites now use Google for hosting the jQuery files.

Comment: yeah, because google is known for being so unreliable (sarcasm)

Comment: It is completely unreliable when the file is blocked by firewalls.  You new?

Comment: i guess so, because i'm surprised there are firewalls that block *google*.  why not block the whole web then?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear your cache and do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) of your browser. You may have cached some bad javascript.