# "Expected identifier, string or number" error when using IE7

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with IE7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91656/problems-with-ie7)

As of this morning, when I go to any StackExchange 2.0 site, IE7 is showing an error icon, with the following associated error:

[image]

I've cleared my cache, etc. (as in the reply to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-viewing-stackoverflow-in-ie7)), but no luck.

Any suggestions, aside from using Firefox or another browser?